# Cleveref and Listings, caption and labels

Tags: captions, listings, labels, languages, cleveref

I tried to look for an answer for this specific situation, but couldn't find one.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,italian]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document} 
\lstinputlisting[
    caption=test,
    label=lst:test
]{test.c}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=test2,label=lst:test2]
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

Testo di esempio con riferimento a \Cref{lst:test} e \Cref{lst:test2}

\end{document}
```

The code in `test.c` is the same as in the `lstlisting` environment. The output I get is:

[image: Result of MWE]

As you can see, the `Cref` commands are translated correctly in "Elenco", but the caption still says "Listing".

I tried adding

```
\crefname{listing}{codice}{codici}
\crefname{listing}{Codice}{Codici}
```

explicitly, to see what the result would be; it changes the `\Cref`s but not the caption.

What's going on? Am I tackling the problem from the wrong perspective?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Elenco}` might help

Comment: That fixes it, thanks. Still, I'm wondering if this shouldn't be addressed by the `cleveref` package: what if I decide to change the language of my article?

Comment: I wouldn't say this is really `cleveref` related but more related to `lstlisting` not responding to the language selected via `babel`.

Comment: With `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\Cref@listing@name}
\makeatother` you can automatically set the name of the listing in the caption to equal to the output of `\Cref`. With this, the caption should adapt to a language change.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If you wish to put that in an answer, I'll mark as accepted.